# Firebase Register and Login button using HTML and Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-authentication

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HandMeDownHarbor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">

    <h1>Welcome to<br>HandMeDownHarbor</h1>
    <h2>New User? Register</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="email" id="emailInputReg" placeholder="Enter your email here"><br><br>
      <input type="password" id="passwordInputReg" placeholder="Enter your password"><br><br>
      <button type="submit" id="regClick">Register</button><br><br>
    </form>


    <h2>Already have an Account? Login</h2>
    <form>
      <input type="email" id="emailInputLog" placeholder="Enter your email here"><br><br>
      <input type="password" id="passwordInputLog" placeholder="Enter your password"><br><br>
      <button type="submit" id="logClick">Login</button><br>
    </form>

    <p id="profile-info"></p>

  </div>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the HTML code.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
...
  };
  
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  const database = firebase.database();

  document.getElementById("regClick").addEventListener("click", register);
  document.getElementById("logClick").addEventListener("click", login);

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      displayProfileInfo();
    });
  });

  function register() {
    const emailInput = document.getElementById('emailInputReg');
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordInputReg');
  
    const email = emailInput.value;
    const password = passwordInput.value;
  
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('User registered:', user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Oops! Error registering user:', error.message);
      });
  }
  
  function login() {
    const emailInputLogin = document.getElementById('emailInputLog');
    const passwordInputLogin = document.getElementById('passwordInputLog');
  
    const emailLogin = emailInputLogin.value;
    const passwordLogin = passwordInputLogin.value;
  
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailLogin, passwordLogin)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const user = userCredential.user;
        console.log('User Successfully logged in:', user);
        

        <a href="dashboard.html">dashboard</a>

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error logging in:', error.message);

        if (error.code === 'auth/user-not-found') {
            alert('User not found!');
        }
        else if (error.code === 'auth/wrong-password'){
            alert('Incoreect Password!')
        }
        else{
            alert('error logging in!')
        }
      });
  }
  
  function displayProfileInfo() {
    const profileInfo = document.getElementById('profile-info');
    const user = auth.currentUser;
  
    if (user) {
      profileInfo.innerHTML = `<p>Welcome, ${user.email}!</p>`;
    } else {
      profileInfo.innerHTML = '<p>Log in to view profile information.</p>';
    }
  }
```

and this is the javascript code.

I am trying to do the user registration and login using firebase authentication. but when I type in email and password and click on register. nothing happens. user is not registered. Also when i created a user manually in firebase, and then tried logging in, but it is redirected to page not found.